# Using Q_ENUM and Q_PROPERTY for enum class in qml

Tags: c++, qt

There is a class for storing enums

```
class EnumerationStorage
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_CLASSINFO("RegisterEnumClassesUnscoped", "false")
public:

    EnumerationStorage() = delete;

    enum class A
    {
        state1,
        state2,
    };
    Q_ENUM(A)
};
```

There is another class in which I want to use enum

```
class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(EnumerationStorage::A a READ readA NOTIFY aChanged)
public:


}
```

```
int main(...)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<EnumerationStorage::A>("A");
    qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject(EnumerationStorage::staticMetaObject, "EnumerationStorage", 1, 0, "EnumerationStorage", "Access to enums & flags only");
}
```

How to use all this in qml? Because `console.log (EnumerationStorage.A.state1)` outputs as 0, and `console.log (client.a)` outputs as state1 (my initial value in the constructor). If `qRegisterMetaType <EnumerationStorage :: A> ("A")`; remove, then this property `client.a` cannot be read. How to put it all together so that everything works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue!!!! You need to specify the full type with all namespaces in Q_PROPERTY

Comment: you might want to add a code example to improve your answer, would be very helpful for future readers :)

Comment: Yes, a code example would help, I have the same issue!

Comment: I am searching exactly for this and I could use some code example :)

Comment: if you register a type in qt meta system you need to register it with full path including namespaces
something like this: 
```qRegisterMetaType<mlfc::model::qmlTempsFanSpeeds*>("const mlfc::model::qmlTempsFanSpeeds*");```

Comment: And in Q_PROPERTY the same 
```Q_PROPERTY(mlfc::EnumerationStorage::FanMode fanMode READ fanMode NOTIFY fanModeChanged)```

Answer (score 0):

Add `priority` `Enum` in `c++` for [using](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/properties.html#a-simple-example) in `qml`

```
 class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Priority priority READ priority WRITE setPriority NOTIFY priorityChanged)

public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyClass();

    enum Priority { High, Low, VeryHigh, VeryLow };
    Q_ENUM(Priority)

    void setPriority(Priority priority)
    {
        m_priority = priority;
        emit priorityChanged(priority);
    }
    Priority priority() const
    { return m_priority; }

signals:
    void priorityChanged(Priority);

private:
    Priority m_priority;
};
```

in `QML` :

```
import "your registered class" 1.0
 QmlCallFile{priority :  Low}
```